# .Net is not connecting to the DB

Tags: .net, database, connection

The below-listed is the code in a “.aspx.vb” file. However, it does not connect to the SQL 2008 DB. Is there an error in the code? Is there an alternate of executing the below-listed Stored Procedure? Thank you for your anticipated answer.

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConStr").ToString())
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

con.Open()
Dim units As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtUnits"), TextBox)
Dim weight As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtWeight"), TextBox)
Dim length As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtLength"), TextBox)
Dim height As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtHeight"), TextBox)
Dim width As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtWidth"), TextBox)
Dim fclass As RadComboBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("ddlFreightClass"), RadComboBox)

cmd = New SqlCommand("spShipmentsLineValueInsert", con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LoadNumber", Convert.ToInt64(Session("loadNumber"))))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Units", Convert.ToInt16(units.Text)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Weight", Convert.ToDecimal(weight.Text)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Length", Convert.ToDecimal(length.Text)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Width", Convert.ToDecimal(width.Text)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Height", Convert.ToDecimal(height.Text)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FreightClass", fclass.SelectedItem.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DefaultMeasure", defaultMeasure))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SessionID", userCode))

Dim RetVal As String = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

con.Close()
```

Comment: that "Constr" looks like an invalid Connection String.

Comment: If the connection fails, or if there is a problem executing the command, an Exception should be thrown.  Catch that Exception and look at the Message property.

Comment: Do you get any errors/exceptions?

Comment: do you receive any error?

Comment: @DJBurb: How's that?  It will load the connection string from app.config using the name "ConStr".

Comment: can you show the connection string that is in the app.config?

Answer (score 1):

your connection string must be like this :

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConStr").ConnectionString
```

example :
your key in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="ConStr" 
       connectionString=
             "server=MYSERVER; Database=MYDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

your code to fetch connection string from web.config :

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConStr").ConnectionString)
```

Comment: That is not correct, the `ToString` method of the `ConnectionStringSettings` class looks like this `return this.ConnectionString;`.

Answer (score -1):

usually the Connection String looks like this pattern `Data Source= *database path*`

Comment: The connection string is being pulled from configuration, therefore until we can see the actual connection string (or a form of it) we have to assume there is nothing wrong with the code.